# Using GetGridHtml in a controller in Umbraco 10

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, umbraco, .net-6.0

I have made a simple Api controller on my umbraco website, that simply searches some nodes for some properties and returns the content from those properties in json.
One of the properties is an umbraco grid. Technically that is also json, and I could successfully get the content with some elaborate JObject querying. But from the view side there is access to a "GetGridHtml" helper function that does that for you.
So my question is, how do I achieve that in a controller? I got the node as IPublishedContent which incidentally has that helper function, but it wants an IHtmlHelper which isn't available in this context. So what do I do?

```
        [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/myapp/version/")]
    public IActionResult GetLatestMyAppVersion()
    {
        var releaseNote = _umbracoHelper.ContentAtXPath("//releaseNoteList").First().Children().OrderByDescending(x => x.Value<DateTime>("releaseDate")).First();
        var ver = releaseNote.Value<string>("myAppReleaseVersion");
        var date = releaseNote.Value<DateTime>("releaseDate");
        
        var desc = releaseNote.GetGridHtml(?????, "mainContent", "Clean"); // this is where IHtmlHelper is needed

        return Ok(new { Application = "MyApp", Version = ver, ReleaseDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), Description = desc });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Ihtmlhelper inside the controller method, I suggest you could inject it by inside the controller construct method and then you could use it inside your codes.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IHtmlGenerator _htmlGenerator;
    private readonly IHtmlHelper _helper;

    public HomeController(IHtmlHelper helper, IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _helper = helper;
        _htmlGenerator = htmlGenerator; 
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did try that but it wouldnt work, I dont have the exception here in front of me but the compiler said that the htmlhelper needed some instantiation of some sort.

Comment: Since we don't have the _umbracoHelper, we don't know what it need, the ihtmlhelper need construct firstly then it could use.